# Date attributes from form, not being saved in database but availabe as params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, parameters

I have an strange problem since Rails 3.2 update.

I have this two models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :educations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :educations, :reject_if => lambda {|c| c[:school_name].blank?}, :allow_destroy => true
  ...
end

class Education < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  ...
end
```

In the database:

```
create_table :educations do |t|
  t.integer :user_id
  t.integer :school_id
  t.date :start
  t.date :end
  t.string :concentration
  t.timestamps
end
```

In a form, I have this:

```
= date_select('user[educations_attributes]', "start", :index => "index", :discard_day => :true, :start_year => 1950, :include_blank => true, :class => 'mini')
```

When I send the form with PUT the params are like this:

```
Started PUT "/users/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-01-26 10:03:35 +0100
Processing by UsersController#update as XML
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"educations_attributes"=>{ "1327568594259"=>{"school_name"=>"Test", "concentration"=>"Test concentration", "start(3i)"=>"", "start(2i)"=>"10", "start(1i)"=>"2003", "end(3i)"=>"", "end(2i)"=>"12", "end(1i)"=>"2010", "_destroy"=>""}}}
```

And the Database Insert is like this:

```
  [1m[35mSQL (0.3ms)[0m  INSERT INTO `educations` (`concentration`, `created_at`, `end`, `school_id`, `start`, `updated_at`, `user_id`) VALUES ('Test concentration', '2012-01-26 09:03:35', NULL, 14, NULL, '2012-01-26 09:03:35', 1)
```

Anyone has an idea why is this for? The index in the params seems to be correct.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Ok, it seems like the problem is being caused by the :discard_day => :true   If the day is not included Rails is ignoring the date. Is it a bug? Should I tell the model about considering "dayless" dates someway?